# getElementByID() for web user control not working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have made a `web user control` (.ascx) which consists of the two html `textbox` and two  `input buttons`, when I try to do `document.getElementById('<%=ControlID.ClientID%>')` it returns null. what could i have done wrong ?

source code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function intilize() {
        var x = document.getElementById('<%=JSNumeric_Control.ClientID%>');
    }

</script>

<table class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td >
        <My:UserInfoBoxControl ID="JSNumeric_Control" runat="server" />
            </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="intilize()" /><br />
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the code for the Numbric.cs, the following are the property used and in page load i am using JavaScript to assign all the events for the HTML inputs:

```
public partial class NumricCounter : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string defualtValue = "0";
        public double defaultIncrementValue = 1;
        public int defaultPrecsionValue = 0;

        public string Button_Add_ClientID
        {
            get { return Button_Add.ClientID; }
        }

        public string Button_Subtract_ClientID
        {
            get { return Button_Subtract.ClientID; }
        }

        //Set and Get for all these properties. (Code Omitted)
        public string Text;

        public double IncrementValue;

        public int PrecsionValue;

        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Text_Output.Value = this.Text;
                Button_Add.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Add(" + IncrementValue.ToString() + "," + PrecsionValue.ToString() + ");");
                Button_Subtract.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Subtract(" + this.IncrementValue.ToString() + "," + this.PrecsionValue.ToString() + ")");
                Text_Output.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "check(" + this.PrecsionValue.ToString() + ");");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where did you put "document.getElementById('<%=ControlID.ClientID%>')" can you post the webform code ?

Comment: have you checked the rendered page source to see if the controls that you expected to be rendered were?  Also providing source would make it easier for us to help answer the question.

Comment: Which element are you expecting to get returned by that? I wouldn't expect that to return the textboxes or input buttons... What is the HTML output of your control (ie post rendering) and what is the value of ControlID.ClientID that it is trying to look up? I'm thinking that the clientID is probably only goign to appear as a prefix for those other elements.

Comment: You don't need to use `script language` attribute

Comment: I am trying to add an event using javascript on both the input buttons inside the user control.

Comment: look at the source of the page in the browser, compare what is rendered for <%=ControlID.ClientID%> with the actual client id of the control.

Comment: Can you just instead use `JSNumeric_Control.Button1.ClientID` or similar (assuming your inner controls are exposed appropriately)?

Comment: @BenRobinson: I don't think we know if the control actually renders any HTML with its ID on do we?

Comment: @Chris yeah good point i had assumed it must otherwise what the OP is trying to do makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing your function:

```
function intilize() {
        var x = document.getElementById('<%=JSNumeric_Control.ClientID%>');
    }
```

with this:

```
function intilize() {
        var x = document.getElementById('JSNumeric_Control');
    }
```

The `getElementById` should read the ID of the element from the rendored html.

Comment: I don't understand what your last line means. getelementbyID won't read any IDs from anywhere, it will just search for something with that given ID. And that ID is less likely to exist than the one returned by JSNumeric_Control.ClientID (which may or may not be what you have hardcoded).

Comment: getElementById searches the html mark up for an element with a specific ID. This means it will search the rendored HTML and not the code the HTML is loaded from.

Answer (score 1):

`JSNumeric_Control.ClientID` will return the ClientID of the control if it were rendered to the page. It's existance doesn't necessarily mean that there will be HTML on the final page that has that ID.

For example if you create a control that just outputs two buttons you will give each of those buttons different IDs that are not the same as the control that they live in. Often you might create a container `div` that you will put around all other content which you will give the ID of the Control to for easy finding but there is no reason for this to exist.

What you should do is either make sure that your control does create this HTML container with the ID of your control or you should refer specifically to the client ID of the items inside your control.

```
var button1 = document.getElementById('<%=JSNumeric_Control.Button1.ClientID%>');
```

Comment: When i tried document.getElementById('<%=JSNumeric_Control.Button_Add.ClientID%>');it gave me an error :"'JavaScriptNumricControl.NumricCounter.Button_Add' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: That is a different line of code than the one I suggested. For my suggestion to work you would have to make the buttons in your control accessible via a public property or as @mayor suggested you could just expose their `ClientID` properties.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the DOM there's no element with Id = ClientID of your UserInfoBoxControl. The controls inside your user control will have other Ids, like 'JSNumeric_Control_Button1', 'JSNumeric_Control_TextBox1' etc.  If you need to get both of the input buttons, you can do one of the following:

1. Use jquery selector to find all inputs with type = button and id starting with <%=JSNumeric_Control.ClientID%>
2. Add two new properties to your control - FirstButtonClientID and SecondButtonClientID that will provide you with clientIDs of your buttons. Then you can use it in javascript.
3. Create custom javascript object which will represent your usercontrol and provide necessary functionality.

Comment: how do you the ClientID property to the controls ?

Comment: Let's assume your user control contains two buttons and their IDs are 'Button1' and 'Button2'.

New properties in your user control will look as following:

public string FirstButtonClientID
{
 get
 {
   return Button1.ClientID;
 }
}

public string SecondButtonClientID
{
 get
 {
   return Button2.ClientID;
 }
}

And your javascript:

var b1 = document.getElementById('<%=JSNumeric_Control.FirstButtonClientID%>');
var b2 = document.getElementById('<%=JSNumeric_Control.SecondButtonClientID%>');

Comment: When i tried what you mentioned above it gave me an error :"'JavaScriptNumricControl.NumricCounter.Button_Add' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: Is NumricCounter a panel in which Button_Add is located?

Comment: No it's the name of the ascx file (NumricCounter.ascx)

Comment: is it the same file which contains markup for UserInfoBoxControl?

Comment: no UserInfoBoxControl is the register tag for the user control:    <%@ Register TagPrefix="My" TagName="UserInfoBoxControl" Src="~/NumricCounter.ascx" %>

Comment: Ok, so did you add FirstButtonClientID and SecondButtonClientID properties into NumricCounter.cs file?

Comment: Oddly enough this worked for me but i don't know why : JSNumeric_Control.FindControl("Button_Add").ClientID;

Comment: Can you show the related part of NumricCounter.cs file and your javascript in page's markup?

Comment: I have posted the code for the Nubmric.cs and the javascript code is already posted or you want the markup for the user control ?

Comment: Check if this script is working (on form markup, intilize() method): var addButton = document.getElementById('<%=JSNumeric_Control.Button_Add_ClientID%>');

Comment: the variable x returns null, as i have stated before the only way is to use "UserControlID.FindControl("SubControlID").ClientID atleast thats what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely trying to search the DOM before it's been loaded. Try putting your code inside an onload handler:

```
document.onload = function () {
    alert(document.getElementById('<%=ControlID.ClientID%>'));
}
```

This makes sure that the code isn't executed before you actually have all of the DOM loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Button_Add is the control id inside the user control
var x = document.getElementByID(JSNumeric_Control.FindControl("Button_Add").ClientID);
```